# apply function to a DataFrame GroupBy and return fewer columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to group my `DataFrame` then apply a function of several columns which returns a single result.

```
In [25]: length = 100
In [26]: rnd = np.random.random
In [27]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict(group=np.random.choice(['a','b','c'], length), foo=rnd(length), bar=rnd(length)))
In [28]: df.head()
Out[28]: 
        bar       foo group
0  0.068853  0.201808     a
1  0.148494  0.722194     c
2  0.902275  0.865231     b
3  0.933513  0.843651     a
4  0.910224  0.671588     a
```

But if I do an `aggregate`, I get the result returned twice (once per remaining column after the `GroupBy`.) What am I doing wrong?

```
In [29]:  df.groupby('group').agg(lambda g: sum(g.bar + g.foo))
Out[29]: 
             bar        foo
group                      
a      36.937812  36.937812
b      33.021105  33.021105
c      30.274639  30.274639
```

All I really want is a `Series` with the same results as `Out[29]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because `agg` tend to keep the same `ndim` as original group rather than squeeze the group from `ndim=2` to `ndim=1`. That's to say, your subgroup is nx2 `ndarray`, the calculation indeed returns a scalar but it then broadcast to a non-squeezed `ndarray` with 1x2 (so it's still 2-d array with original columns). Or, put in another way, the rule `agg` is to aggregate a subgroup dataframe (nx2) across `axis=0` so the returned shape must be 1x2. so even if you've got a scalar result, it will be broadcasted to 1x2 when `.agg` return the result.

This can be fixed using `apply` rather than `agg`, as `apply` has no constraint on the returned shape.

```
df.groupby('group').apply(lambda g: sum(g.bar + g.foo))

group
a    39.4419
b    27.2982
c    25.3910
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't mind doing it by steps why not do as follows:

```
In [52]:
df = df.groupby('group').sum()
df['foobar']=df.foo + df.bar
new_series = df.loc[:,'foobar']
new_series

Out[52]:
group
a        33.047944
b        30.503071
c        30.899891
Name: foobar, dtype: float64

In [53]:
type(new_series)

Out[53]:
pandas.core.series.Series
```